# How to fix the issue of unicode utf-8 in Crystal report 2016 when get data from oracle

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I'm using Crystal report 2016 connect with oracle, if i export file pdf on my local, it display unicode utf-8 (vietnamese) normal. but if i export file on my server dev, it was break and error font...

my version is 14.2.2

How to fix the problem ? many thank

example of error:
[image]

Comment: I assume it is rather a font issue, (i.e. display issue) rather than a problem with the encoding. Which font do you use? Does it support Vietnamese characters?

Comment: hi @WernfriedDomscheit: i haven't checked font using, if you know check which font in CR, please could you tell me?

Comment: really hard to understand why i export from my local pc it display normal. but on server dev environment it cannot display correct..